# If I want to ask the boot sector format or linux kernel data structure,where should I ask? stackoverflow or programmers or cstheory?

Tags: discussion, technology

I followed this link:
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/is-operating-system-development-a-subset-of-software-development-stack-overflow

What I found is if I want to ask something about detailed OS structure format or protected mode or linux kernel structure design methodology, I have no way to ask.

Stack Overflow : programming but not related to boot sector format.

Programmers.SE : High level skills but not related to boot sector format.

CStheory.SE : Only theory(algorithms...) but not related to boot sector format.

Am I right?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask something about detailed OS structure format or protected mode or linux kernel structure design methodology

#### What:

- What is the current or competing formats? --> Nowhere - look it up via google.  You're a big boy if you're dealing with these questions, for you this should be considered general reference.  If you aren't a big boy and you need someone else to google for you, then superuser might be acceptable.

#### Why:

- Advantages of this format over another? --> **Programmers** - This is essentially an architecture decision.

#### How:

- How do I write safe, robust, boot sector code? --> **Stack Overflow** - This is where the rubber meets the road - you know the current standard, you know why you'd follow given techniques, now how do you do it.

There is not single site that covers all aspects of any one topic.  You'll have to pick and choose which site you're going to ask depending on the exact information you want.  For some problems you are expected to consult with several sites - you won't be able to get all of your information in one place, nevermind in one question.

Answer (score 5):

At first glance, "boot sector format" makes me think you have a [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/) question. It might help if you posted a copy of your proposed question, because the topic alone might not be enough.